# R - Looping over Columns then Rows

Tags: r, loops

I was wondering if anyone could help me with a problem I'm having in R. It involves looping over columns and rows. The example below should be clear hopefully. I have a 5x5 table below. Using row 1 as an example, I would like to count the number of times V2:V5 are lower than the value in V1, and express that as a decimal.

```
set.seed(1)
data=as.data.frame(replicate(5, rnorm(5)))

      V1         V2         V3          V4          V5
 1 -0.6264538 -0.8204684  1.5117812 -0.04493361  0.91897737
 2  0.1836433  0.4874291  0.3898432 -0.01619026  0.78213630
 3 -0.8356286  0.7383247 -0.6212406  0.94383621  0.07456498
 4  1.5952808  0.5757814 -2.2146999  0.82122120 -1.98935170
 5  0.3295078 -0.3053884  1.1249309  0.59390132  0.61982575


test=lapply(2:5,function(a){
ifelse(data[1,1]<=data[1,a],1,0)})
testtable=(as.data.frame(table(unlist(test)))[1,2])/4
testtable
[1] 0.25
```

This means that in row 1, only 1/4 values in V2:V5 are lower than V1. I'd like to use an additional loop for this to go through each row separately. I tried:

```
test2=lapply(2:5,function(a){
lapply(1:5,function(b){
ifelse(original_permuted_results[b,1]<=original_permuted_results[a,b],1,0)
(as.data.frame(table(unlist(test)))[1,2])/4})})
```

Resulting in

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 0.25

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 0.25

[[1]][[3]]
[1] 0.25

[[1]][[4]]
[1] 0.25

[[1]][[5]]
[1] 0.25


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 0.25
```

And continues like that, just printing out 0.25 as the result for the remainder of the loops. It should produce, ignoring the words in brackets:

```
(for row 1) 0.25  
(for row 2) 0.25
(for row 3) 0
(for row 4) 1
(for row 5) 0.25
```

I had a trawl through the archives but couldn't find anything. My actual data has 300+ rows and 10000 columns, but the output I'm trying to achieve is exactly the same. If anyone has any suggestions that would be very must appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

does this work,

```
vec<-rowSums(data<data$V1)/4

> vec
[1] 0.25 0.25 0.00 1.00 0.25
```

Comment: Is this really any different than @BrodieG's answer?

Comment: @AnandaMahto It is more concise.

Comment: not really, no printing but a vector here, and did answer before seeing BrodieG's version, although posted later

Comment: @nograpes, I think BrodieG just missed the part about "ignoring the words in brackets" from the question and thought they wanted to recreate that particular output.

Comment: Thanks! This was the most concise solution, but the others all worked too! This will save me loads of time. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need loops.  You can take advantage of vectorization:

```
cat(paste("(for row", 1:nrow(df), ")", 
  rowSums(df[, 1] > df[, 2:5]) / 4),    # this is where it all happens
  sep="\n"
)
```

Produces:

```
(for row 1 ) 0.25
(for row 2 ) 0.25
(for row 3 ) 0
(for row 4 ) 1
(for row 5 ) 0.25
```

Here we take advantage of `>` coercing the RHS to a matrix in order to do the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Very similar to @BrodieG, but perhaps a little clearer:

```
# Find when each column is less than the first column.
lower.than.first<-sapply(data[2:5],function(x) x<data[,1])
# Calculate the proportion 
num.true<-rowSums(lower.than.first) # TRUE is 1, and FALSE is 0, when summing.
# Get the proportion.
props<-num.true/ncol(lower.than.first)
# [1] 0.25 0.25 0.00 1.00 0.25
```

Comment: Compare your first line to the simpler `lower.than.first <- data[,2:5] < data[,1]`. The `sapply` is completely unnecessary.

Comment: @John I agree that it is functionally equivalent. However, this isn't Code Golf, I thought it would be instructive to someone trying to understand how it works. Other solutions posted here are even more concise.

Comment: One might argue that all code is "code golf"...:) But if you're going to be instructive it might help to explain the reason, otherwise it's confusing to a newbie as to why it's in there in this instance and not in others. You state your answer is clearer. Saying why this line is clearer might help.

Comment: The reason why I put in the functionally unnecessary `sapply` is because the user seems to understand how `sapply` works, and may find it easier to understand than a concise use of `<`. I could be wrong. I would find it difficult to argue that all code is "Code Golf", but perhaps this is not the best forum for that discussion.